# T-SQL Date Function

Tags: t-sql, function, date

I have a T-SQL script that runs every weekday.  The script does a lookup for new customers in the past 24 hours, with the exceptionof Monday it will do a lookup in the past 72 hours (Friday through Sunday)

```
Select FirstName, LastName, CustomerID, Date
FROM Customers
WHERE 
(
  (
     DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GetDate())=2 AND 
     DATEDIFF(DAY, Customers.Date, GetDate()) <= 3 AND 
     DATEDIFF(DAY, Customers.Date, GetDate()) >= 1
   ) 
   OR DATEDIFF(DAY, Customers.Date, GetDate()) = 1
)
```

I need to change this to do a lookup 30 days prior instead.
ANy ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Using `GetDate()` within a query is chasing a moving target, impacts performance, and may produce curious results, e.g. as the date changes.  It is almost always a better idea to capture the current date/time in a variable and then use that value as needed.  This is more important across multiple statements as in a stored procedure.  The most common reason to use `GetDate()` multiple times is when capturing the start and end times for a long running operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, Customers.Date, GetDate()) <= 30
```